# date function will return different date if date changes while executing the query?

Tags: sql-server

```
select * from abc where transaction_date = DATE ;
```

If query started at 11:45 pm and runs for 30 min , after 12 am which date records will be filtered out by query ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no function called `date`.

The built in functions like `getdate()` are evaluated at the beginning of the execution and treated as [runtime constants](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions/).

If you wrap them in a scalar UDF they will then be reevaluated for each row though so will then be dependant on time the row is processed.

Comment: lets say, if i started query on 18th may and date change to 19th it will return all records for 18th only ? am i right?

Comment: yes, as long as you called the built in function directly and didn't wrap it in a user defined scalar UDF

Answer (score 1):

If by `DATE` you meant i.e. `GETDATE()` only one day will be returned. It's computed when a query starts.

Comment: yes , i meant the same any of date function . Thanks , got my answer.